# How to remove an item from the array on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table with few rows and delete button. I have stored all the list of table in an array 'arr'. How can I remove the selected item from that array on button click.

```
<table id="sum_table">
  <tr class="titlerow">   
    <th>S.N.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td><button class="dm" data-id="0">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Henry</td>
    <td><button class="dm" data-id="1">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
</table>

 var arr= [
  ["name", John],
  ["name", Henry]
  ];

  function clickHandler(clickEvent) {

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Take a look at `array.splice` method

Comment: find the index of the item and as @JohanP told use `arr.splice(index,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your array need to be an array of object and not an array of array**. Also you can give a class to the name column of a table to access its value and then use `findIndex` to find the index of the name attribute in array and then `splice` to remove it.

```js
  $(function(){
        var arr= [
          {"name": "John"},
          {"name": "Henry"}
       ];
       $('.dm').click(function(){
            var val = $(this).closest('tr').find(".name").text();
            console.log(val);
            var index = arr.findIndex(function(item) {return item.name == val})
            console.log(index)
            arr.splice(index, 1)
            console.log(arr);
        })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table">
  <tr class="titlerow">   
    <th>S.N.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="name">John</td>
    <td><button class="dm" data-id="0">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="name">Henry</td>
    <td><button class="dm" data-id="1">Remove</button></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you send the name of the person on click event then you can use `array.splice` method as shown below :

```
for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(arr[i] === name) {
       arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

You have to note that it will delete all the values from array which has the same name.

With Index - Just send the data-id on click of button and splice the array on that index

```
arr.splice(dataid, 1)
```

Comment: Why will you like to change the content of original array

Comment: @brk Its not about changing the contents of original array, just letting him know that using this method will delete all the contents of an array having the same name